# How can I add Done button to the number pad in swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard, numpad

How can I add Done button to the number pad in swift and then use this button to hide the keyboard?

Comment: Please show the code that you have so far.  This is not a site for people to request tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are planning on coding a whole keyboard from scratch you can only select existing keyboard types.

There is a really good article http://www.weheartswift.com/make-custom-keyboard-ios-8-using-swift/ which shows how to create a custom keyboard that may help you.